# Using nativescript-ng2-magic

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a question. I wanted to start implementing a web (desktop) app and, with almost the same code base) with nativescript the native app for iOs/Android. 
My question is, I have already implemented the native app, can I use the nativesript-modules (like color, ui/page, etc.) also for the web app?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't use those.

I think nativescript-ng2-magic and advanced-angular-seed (same author) are made to be used the other way around.

You have to refactor your services to be platform agnostic (as they should be) and the custom Component decorator takes care of switching templates. If you have lot of accessing nativescript-modules in your component's code, the switch is not going to be easy.

Comment: ok thank you! I will try and see how many work it is :( There are some components that I have to adapt but I use only color ui/page etc.